# Angular Bootstrap Ui-select

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-select

I am trying to use the ui-select directive in my angularjs but it is not displaying, i tried following the documentation and this is what i did:

```
 <ui-select ng-model="form.gender" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-choices repeat="gender in genders">
        {{ gender.name }}
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Then I have an array of genders:

```
$scope.genders = [
    {
        name: 'Male'
    },
    {
        name: 'Female'
    }
];
```

I haven't really used this directive before so I'm a bit confused as to what i am doing wrong.

There are no errors being displayed in my browser console, i have included the module in my app as well.

I want to use it for more than a simple dropdown of genders but i figure this is a start if i can do this then i won't have any more problems. :)

**Edit:** So i cleared my browser cache and refreshed my page and this time i did notice an error:

```
Error: [ui.select:transcluded] Expected 1 .ui-select-match but got '0'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must visit this link and follow its examples.

[You can follow its examples](http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

I personally prefer to use uiselect2, its more powerful and simple than uiselect

[link of uiselect2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2)

Comment: I followed the link and saw what i did wrong however even after reading what they had there i am still clueless as to how the ui-select and ui-select-match and ui-select-choices work or what those directives even do.

Comment: Also when i try to use the 'selecticize' them i get errors: http://prntscr.com/8gx7ax

Comment: I personally prefer to use uiselect2, its so simple and powerfull than uiselect [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2), if you got your answer , please mark it as answer :)

Comment: ui-select2 has been deprecated in favor of ui-select for quite some time.  Not sure why you are recommending it.

Answer (score 6):

just add a class named as the tag.

```
 <ui-select ng-model="form.gender" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-choices class="ui-select-choices" repeat="gender in genders">
        {{ gender.name }}
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: adding ui-select-match is also required in case you are using it

Comment: Worked for me. Problem was with class, has to be the same as derective.

Answer (score 3):

> Error: [ui.select:transcluded] Expected 1 .ui-select-match but got '0'.

This error was fixed recently at Github page.
Just update ui-select to v0.14.3.

Reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/224

Answer (score 0):

.ui-select-toggle > .caret { pointer-events: none }
fixes the problem of 
error: [ui.select:transcluded] Expected 1 .ui-select-match but got '0'.
for me

Answer (score 0):

As @Caner Çakmak said, I added a class named as tag in both ui-select-choices and ui-select-match

Ex:

```
<ui-select ng-model="form.gender" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match class="ui-select-match" [etc...etc....etc]>
    <ui-select-choices class="ui-select-choices" repeat="gender in genders">
    {{ gender.name }}
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

And it worked! Thanks

PS: I am using ui-select v0.19.X and Angular v1.5.X (that seems to be when this error occurs)